# Javascript events in Firefox for javascript assigned listeners

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling

OK, so there's a question that gets asked around here a lot about Firefox not responding to window.event, where instead you need to add an extra parameter to the function. I have no problems with that; my problem is how the heck do I do that if I want to assign the event listeners from within a different Javascript function?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is the common effect when you can have a form box that has grey text that would say, for example, "Your name..." and then when you click the box the text disappears and the color changes to black; unfocus with the box still empty and the prompt text will return.

Now, instead of coding this directly for every page I want to use it on, I'm trying to make a function that I can call with the ID of the form and it will automatically apply this to every input element. Here's the code:

```
function fadingForm(formElementID, endColor)
{
  var form = document.getElementById(formElementID);

  for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++)
  {
    form.elements[i].originalValue = form.elements[i].value;
    form.elements[i].originalColor = form.elements[i].style.color;
    form.elements[i].changedColor  = endColor;

    // Somehow I need to get that event parameter in here I guess?
    // I tried just putting the variable event in as a parameter,
    //   but as you'd expect, that doesn't work.
    form.elements[i].onfocus = function() { focused(); };
    form.elements[i].onblur  = function() { blurred(); };
  }
}

function focused(e)
{
  evt = e || window.event;
  element = evt.target;

  if(element.value == "" || element.value == element.originalValue)
  {
    element.value = "";
    element.style.color = element.changedColor;
  }
}

function blurred(e)
{
  evt = e || window.event;
  element = evt.target;

  if(element.value == "" || element.value == element.originalValue)
  {
    element.value = element.originalValue;
    element.style.color = element.originalColor;
  }
}
```

And of course, this works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, etc...just not Firefox.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `form.elements[i].onfocus = focused` or `form.elements[i].onfocus = function(e) { focused(e); }`? ([Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/amXF3/1))

Comment: Wow. Well that was easy! I had it that way because I was originally passing some parameters. Your suggestion of just removing the anonymous function now worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. I posted a proper answer which you are [welcome to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event listeners `focused` and `blurred` accept an event object `e`, but you never provide an event object. The event object that is provided to the anonymous wrapper functions is never used nor passed to `focused`/`blurred`. Thus, `e` is always undefined.

Instead, when you set up your listeners, do:

```
form.elements[i].onfocus = function(e) { focused(e); };
form.elements[i].onblur  = function(e) { blurred(e); };
```

Or even:

```
form.elements[i].onfocus = focused;
form.elements[i].onblur  = blurred;
```

So that the event object is passed directly into your listener functions.

Comment: Ah! Well now I feel stupid :)   Too used to just always using anonymous, parameter-less functions in situations like this to pass constants as parameters and such. Didn't even cross my mind that I could stick a parameter in there!